# echo unicode character as utf8 from file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unicode

When I run `echo "\U0041"` in the terminal I get "A".

However when I run `echo "\U0041"` from within a file say `example.sh` then run it.

`bash ./example.sh` or
`sh ./example.sh`

I get the literal `\U0041`.

Why? How can I echo / print "A" from within the file.

---

**Update**:

- `"$SHELL" --version` -> `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)`
- I upgraded bash to bash-5.1 using brew.
- When I run `echo $'\u0041'` from within a file I do see "A"

My question is now, How do I have a the hex code be a variable, when I can only seem to print uf8 with single quotes, but the variable needs double?

```
HEX='0041'
echo $"\u$HEX"
```

prints: `\u0041`

Comment: Which version of Bash is that? Interactive Bash 5.1.4 just prints "\U0041".

Comment: I'm running a new 2020 mac using `bash-3.2`

Comment: Not `zsh` for the interactive terminal?

Comment: What does `"$SHELL" --version` report in your interactive shell?

Comment: zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)

Comment: I upgraded bash to `bash-5.1` using brew.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `zsh` as the shell in your terminal. Its version of `echo` understands `\uXXXX` escapes. So does the `echo` that's built in to modern versions of `bash` (If using `echo -e` or if the `xdg_echo` shell option is enabled), but the ancient version that comes with Mac OS is too old to have it.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $'\u0041'` prints "A" in [Bash 4.2 onwards](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061). (`$''` has been available since Bash 2.0.) Looks like you're probably running the script in Bash 3.2 and a newer interactive shell.

Comment: I am also trying to log a variable `echo $"\u$hex"` is this possible?

Comment: Updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I received a bit of help on this one but the full solution to my quesiton was this:

1. Update `bash` using homebrew `brew install bash`
2. Use `echo -e` or `printf` from within file.

```
HEX='0041'
echo -e "\u$HEX"
```

3. Run using `bash` not `sh`.

```
$ bash ./example.sh
A
```